I need help to debug my Zeroinfl GLM that causes an error indicating 'NA' and "exactly singular systems"
I am having a problem with my code. I am trying to create a GLM model with Zeroinfl since my data set has many 0's in it. I am trying to study the influence of pond characteristics on pond amphibian diversity but I get an error code that leads to "NA"'s in my summary table.
When I try to create my model :
modele_amphibia <- zeroinfl(diversite_sp_10 ~ surface + date + 
                   substrat + res_hydro + vol_pot_est+
                   creation_restauration + habitat, 
                   data = data_GLM_amphibia, dist = "poisson")

I get this error :

Message d'avis :
Dans value[3L] :
Routine Lapack dgesv : le système est exactement singulier : U[22,22] = 0FALSE

I don't understand how I can fix this.
When I do summary(modele_amphibia)
I get my coefficient numbers but "NA" in all the other columns...
What can I do ?

Hi Gabriel, I suspect you have over-fit your model. The code generally looks fine, but to allow us to troubleshoot you should: 1) provide the package from which you are exporting the zeroingl(...) function, I think it is psci::zeroinfl()?, and 2) provide some example data so that we can see the data structure...try dput(data) and paste results. I would recommend backing off on explanatory variables and building up to see where the error starts occurring. If this becomes a question of model formulation you will be better served by posting to Cross Validated.

it's quite possible that you have some exactly multicollinear variables. You could try X <- model.matrix(~ surface + date + substrat + res_hydro + vol_pot_est+ creation_restauration + habitat, data = data_GLM_amphibia); caret::findLinearCombos(X) to explore further.

By the way, how is pond diversity exactly zero? How are you measuring diversity (species richness, Shannon ...) ?
